# Update Data Attribute Object Property Value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've gotten this to work but I would like to know if there is a straightforward way of accomplishing the update.  I have a div where a data attribute has been assigned.  When the div is clicked, I want one of the properties on the data attribute to be updated.

http://jsfiddle.net/quint/fq7dwsyv/

```
var originalObj = {
  "x": 5,
  "y": 58,
  "selected": 'no'
};
var originalObjString = JSON.stringify(originalObj);    // Convert object to JSON string

$('#test').attr('data-objData', originalObjString);      // Attach data attribute to div

$('#test').on('click', function(event) {
  var originalData = $(this).attr('data-objData');       // Store data attribute value
  var originalDataJSON = JSON.parse(originalData);      // Convert string to object

  originalDataJSON['selected'] = 'yes';                 // Update object property
  var updatedData = JSON.stringify(originalDataJSON);   // Convert object to string and store

  $('#test').attr('data-objData', updatedData);      // Update data attribute on div

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd separate the update into its own function

```
$('[data-example]').click(function() {
  function update(object) {
    object.foo = 'bar';
    return object;
  }

  var original = this.dataset.example;
  original = original && JSON.parse(original) || {};
  this.dataset.example = JSON.stringify(update(original));
});
```

Comment: thanks for providing an answer.  For my use case, your answer will not work.  Thank you for taking the time to respond!

Answer (score 0):

You can store the original object with [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) and mutate it directly without having to store it again with the `.data()` method:

```js
var originalObj = {
  "x": 5,
  "y": 58,
  "selected": 'no'
};

$('#test').data('objData', originalObj);

$('#test').on('click', function(event) {
    $(this).data('objData')['selected'] = 'yes';
    console.log($(this).data('objData'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="test">test me</button>
```

#### Remarks

The above solution assumes you are willing to change the way the object is stored with the element. If on the other hand the value must be stored on an element attribute, then there is not much that can be improved in your code. The steps you take are then all necessary (convert from/to JSON, read from attribute, write to attribute, ...etc).

Note however that writing to element attributes is not considered best practice. If anything, you should use `.prop()` in favour of `.attr()`: it will result in faster code. But you'll not see the change when consulting the element attributes. In other words, you cannot mix `.prop()` with `.attr()`.

If there is no room for change in that either, then I would suggest that you ask this question on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This would be perfect if the data attribute where re-inserted back into the HTML element.  Maybe I'm missing it but when I inspect the #test div, I don't see the data attribute with its key/value pairs.  The situation: HTML elements will have data attributes as specified earlier.  At a later time, the user may interact with an element.  That element's attribute must be updated if selected.  At a later time, I will be reading all of the data attributes for all requisite HTML elements for further processing.

Comment: All what you write is possible with this solution, it is just not implemented as a standard HTML attribute.

Comment: Thanks, @trincot, for the feedback.  I agree; however, at this stage of the development, I want to display the data attribute for each element for a number of reasons.  What I have does work and I will use that.  Thanks for taking the time to provide an answer!

Comment: In case you were already happy with your solution, you should consider posting on http://codereview.stackexchange.com. I just want to add that writing to element attributes is not particularly known for being fast ;-)